# nginx - php-fpm crashing

Tags: nginx, php

I run an API using rackspace cloud servers. We have an auto scale policy for our peak times and we are finding that once or twice a day one of the servers that are spun up is having a problem with php-fpm.

As soon as the server starts receiving traffic is spawns all of its 40 children and then locks up and nginx starts responding with a 502 error message. I can monitor the children in top and they just sit there idle for about 5 minutes and then finally die off and the server can receive traffic again but then the same process starts and it locks up again.

We will have another server running which has the exact same disc image so exactly the same config and it will behave perfectly. Below is my php5-fpm config. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[www.conf]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 40
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 200
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: I just get an error saying max children reached. It's as if the children can only process one request and then just sit there.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the php-fpm per pool configuration option 'listen.backlog' (default: -1=unlimited).
Since sockets are being used, this value is also limited by the system value 'net.core.somaxconn' (default: 128 on most Linux systems).